# Python folium heatmap representation on sample data and original data

Tags: python, dataframe, folium

Whenever I put in the code the map goes blank and does not show anything:

```
lat_long = zip(list(file.Start_Lng), list(file.Start_Lat)) 
map1 = folium.Map() HeatMap(lat_long).add_to(map1) 
map1
```

On the other hand when I change the code as below the map start to display the data:

```
sample_file = file.sample(int(0.1 * len(file)))
lat_lon_pairs = zip(list(sample_file.Start_Lat), list(sample_file.Start_Lng))
map1 = folium.Map() HeatMap(lat_lon_pairs).add_to(map1)
map1
```

Can someone tell me why?
P.S: Also if anyone is curious then this is the dataset I am working on:

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents

Comment: I downloaded the data from kaggle and tried it out. Probably the cause depends on the number of data counts. There are 2845342 data in total, and I tried increasing the number of displayable data sequentially. The heatmap could be displayed up to 1.2 million cases.

Comment: `import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap

lat_long = zip(list(df.Start_Lat[:1200000]), list(df.Start_Lng[:1200000])) 
map1 = folium.Map([df.Start_Lat.mean(), df.Start_Lng.mean()], start_zoom=4)
HeatMap(lat_long).add_to(map1) 
map1`

Comment: Thank you @r-beginners for your reply. I will keep that in mind when I do it next time.